# Constant values in Python

Tags: python

Sometime there is a need to define constant numeric values to be used across our application.

For instance in C language I used to do thing like:

```
#define PI = 3.14
#define MIN = 0
#define MAX = 256
```

What is the equivalent in Python?

[Edit:] To the down voters. The question is not related to syntax. I'm interested in understanding conventions and doing things right in the Python philosophy.

Comment: Just don't assign a new value to the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no really equivalent in Python: just convention: uppercase!
If you write:

```
CST = 10
```

Everyone know that you don't have to change it…